# Cleaning List<double[]> within a given tolerance

Tags: c#, list

I have a List where each double[] has a length of 3. I would like to  clean this list by leaving only those double[] having unique elements within a given tolerance (round up). For instance, a list like the one below:

```
1059.17 0 446.542225842081
1059.17 0 446.542564789741
1059.17 0 446.541759880305
959.167 0 579.827860527898
959.167 0 579.827847296075
```

Should become  this for a given tolerance=two:

```
1059.17 0 446.54,
959.17 0 579.83,
```

Is there a smart way to do this in a neat way?

Comment: Well first of all you can't store them as double. You have to store them as strings, since the amount of decimals displayed will depend on how you format the actual decimal number. You can either do it that way or format the number everywhere you use it.

Comment: why does 959.167 not become 959.17 ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work?

```
public List<double[]> CleanWithTolerance(List<double[]> doubleNumbersList, int tolerance)
{
    var newDoublesNumbersList = new List<double[]>();
    foreach(double[] doubleNumbers in doubleNumbersList)
    {
        var newDoublesNumbers = doubleNumbers.Select(doubleNumber => Math.Round(doubleNumber, tolerance)).ToArray();
        if(newDoublesNumbersList.All(cleanDoubleNumbers => !Enumerable.SequenceEqual(cleanDoubleNumbers, newDoublesNumbers))
        {
            newDoublesNumbersList.Add(newDoublesNumbers);
        }
    }
    return newDoublesNumbersList;
}
```

Comment: Math.Round will round to the nearest, not round up. Math.Ceiling can be used to round up like this `Math.Ceiling(doubleNumber*x)/x` where x is 10^tolerance.

Comment: In the example 446.541759880305 was rounded to 446.54 and for this Math.Round is just fine.

Comment: The text says "given tolerance (round up)". So I guess the question is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that array elements are always in the same order you can create your own comparer that should *know* how to compare double arrays :

```
public class MyDoubleArrComparer : IEqualityComparer<double[]>
{
    public bool Equals(double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(double[] obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And you can create a helper method that will round numbers and remove duplicates :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<double[]> MyFilter(this List<double[]> list, int tolerance)
    {
        var result = list
            .Select(arr =>
            {
                // rounds numbers with precision that is set in tolerance variable
                arr = arr.Select(d => d = Math.Round(d, tolerance)).ToArray();
                return arr;
            }).Distinct(new MyDoubleArrComparer()) // here we use our custom comparer
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now we can start using our helper method :

```
var nums = new List<double[]>()
        {
            new[] {1059.17, 0, 446.542225842081},
            new[] {1059.17, 0, 446.542564789741},
            new[] {1059.17, 0, 446.541759880305},
            new[] {959.167, 0, 579.827860527898},
            new[] {959.167, 0, 579.827847296075},
        };

var result = nums.MyFilter(2);

foreach (var arr in result)
{
    foreach (var d in arr)
    {
       Console.Write(d + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output :

```
1059.17 0 446.54
959.17 0 579.83
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It uses the build-in equality comparisons of anonymous types.

```
List<double[]> data = ...
int tolerance = 2;
var roundedData = data
    .Select(x => new {
        v1 = Math.Round(x[0], tolerance),
        v2 = Math.Round(x[1], tolerance),
        v3 = Math.Round(x[2], tolerance)
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new [] { x.v1, x.v2, x.v3 })
    .ToList();
```